# Objects validating itself using Castle Validators

Tags: nhibernate, model-view-controller, fluent, validation, castle

I have a Task object which has a property of Employee.  Im trying to find the best possible way setting a validation to only allow the certain employees to access the task object.  If the current context user (web/winforms) tries to instantiate the Task object the object should automatically validate itself and return a validation error message.
Can you please advise what is the best way of doing this?

im using Fluent nHibernate and Castle Validators and the front end is asp.net MVC.

```
public class Task:ITask
    {
        public virtual int TaskID { get; set; }
        public virtual TaskStatus TaskStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        **public virtual Employee CreatedByUser { get; set; }**
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [NHibernate load event listener](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events) instead of Castle Validators for this.